# Multiple lines in one value of an embed (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

I am trying to create for my needs an embed with my discord.js bot.
Unfortuanlty I can't figure out how to do multiple lines in **one** value field. I tried with the new line character \n, but this was awful, because my lines were getting really long and unreadable, and you can't just start a new coding line in javascript, because semicolons are optional.

Does someone have an idea? Here is a template:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("EVERY ROLE EXPLAINED")
      .setColor(color)
      .addFields(
          {name: "__Column 1__", value: "line 1\n line 2\line three", inline: true},
          {name: "__Column 2__", value: "line 1\n line 2\line three", inline: true}
      )
```

Comment: Your question is not about the output of the embed but about your source code?

Comment: I mean yeah, as I said I found a away of making new lines, but for my porpuse I need about 10 lines, I dont think it will fit well and in one single source code line with \n everywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the backtick (`) key

```js
// with backtick
console.log(`line 1
line 2
line 3`)

// without backtick
console.log('line 1\nline 2\nline 3')

// same results
```

---

Another idea would be to concatenate multiple strings in a new line.

```js
// with concatenation
console.log('line 1\n' +
'line 2\n' +
'line 3\n')

// without concatenation
console.log('line 1\nline 2\nline 3')

// same results
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var value = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    value += `line ${i}\n`
}
```

OR If you have List(array) of lines you can use:

```js
var value = "";
lines.forEach(line=> {
  value += `${line}\n`
});
```